# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 while using local storage

Tags: javascript

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at index.js:4:20.

Want to store data in local storage but it showing this error
code below

```js
var todoArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoLocal")) || [];
```

Comment: Can we get your code?

Comment: So it means there is not such item in local storage. Maybe type (`toDoLocal` instead of `todoLocal`)?

Comment: `var todoArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoLocal") || '[]');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check to see if something is there before you parse it.

Either

```js
var todoArr = localStorage.getItem("todoLocal") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoLocal")) : [];

// var lsTDL = localStorage.getItem("todoLocal");
// var todoArr =  lsTDL ? JSON.parse(lsTDL) : [];
```

or

```
var todoArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoLocal") || '[]');
```